# Getting Australian visa while in US with valid H-1B status, Advance Parole card (I-512), but expired H-1B visa stamp

Tags: visas, australia, h1b-visas

I'm currently living in US with H-1B status. The status is valid for another year.

My H-1B visa expires in couple of days.

I have applied for a Green Card (I-585) and got EAD + Advance Parole card (I-512) that should allow me back to US. The card expires in some months.

I want to get Australian visa to attend a conference. ( "Visitor visa (subclass 600)".

The visa application form says: "Give details of why the applicant is at their current location, including **the end date of their current visa**."

Does my situation automatically prevent me from getting Australian visa?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because the meaning of "the end date of their current visa" for Australian visa applications submitted in the United States must be objective rather than a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Australian consulates in the US will surely understand that is not necessary to have a valid visa in the passport in order to be in the US legally.  After all, the Australian consul and other consular officers are, like you, living in the US in a nonimmigrant status.

You can read the sentence you quoted as "Give details of why the applicant is at their current location, including the end date of their current immigration status."  Include your current I-94 and I-797 approval notice along with any evidence of your pending AOS application, including the I-512.